# Не получается разобраться с namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript

> Error:(7, 64) TS2339: Property 'Controller' does not exist on type
>   'typeof RealtimeMultiplayerGame'.

```
import SortedLookupTable from "../lib/SortedLookupTable.d.ts";
namespace RealtimeMultiplayerGame.Controller {
    export class FieldController {
        constructor() {
            this.entities = new SortedLookupTable();
            this.players = new SortedLookupTable();
        }
```

Ошибка тут:

```
   namespace RealtimeMultiplayerGame {
        export abstract class AbstractGame {
            constructor() {
                this.setupNetChannel();
                this.setupCmdMap();
                this.fieldController = new RealtimeMultiplayerGame.Controller.FieldController();
            }
```

Немного потыкав понял что проблема в

```
 import SortedLookupTable from "../lib/SortedLookupTable.d.ts";
```

Внутри тут

```
declare let SortedLookupTable:any;
export default SortedLookupTable;
```

Тут что то не так сделал

Answer (score 1):

В общем сделал так, если что поправьте

```
interface SortedLookupTableInterface{

}
declare module "SortedLookupTableModule" {
    export = SortedLookupTable;
}
declare class SortedLookupTable implements SortedLookupTableInterface{

}
```